# How to listen to a backend background event in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, eventos, background, download

Estoy trabajando en frontend con Angular y en backend con Spring.

Estoy intentando realizar una descarga de ficheros en segundo plano por que la descarga tarda bastante.

Mi intención es que al pulsar sobre el botón de descarga la aplicación cree una conexión y puedas seguir usando la aplicación con normalidad mientras espera que el backend termine.

He estado buscando información de como realizar acciones en segundo plano para el backend y para ello estoy usando SseEmitter.

```
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
```

Me gustaría saber cómo crear un hilo entre el frontend y el backend para que se mantenga escuchando hasta que la descarga en el backend termine.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, estamos en la version de SO de español, te recomiendo [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/542295/edit) la pregunta y hacerla en español, de lo contrario acabara cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes la solución a tu pregunta:

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-and-server-sent-events-sse-54c29b4f174d

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!